# For loop works different in Groovy and Java

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy

Please take a look at the following code snippet in **groovy**:

```
def static void main(String... args) {
    def arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    for (int f in arr) {
        Thread.start { print f + ', '}
    }
}
Out: 2, 3, 5, 5, 5,
```

I was surprised by this output. Why "5" was printed several times?
Moreover, everything looks good running equivalent code in **Java**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for (int f : arr) {
        new Thread(() -> { System.out.print(f + ", "); }).start();
    }
}
Out: 1, 5, 4, 3, 2,
```

Can anyone explain why this is the case? Looks like the issue with groovy is in Closure implementation. However, this behaviour is pretty weird. Is it some kind of bug or I just do not realize how groovy works?

Thanks!

Comment: looks like "F" variable gets captured in a wrong way. will be interesting to see the explanation.

Comment: The for loop works exactly the same. It is the way the thread is created that is different

Comment: The issue is you are creating threads, you can't expect threads to be executed in a certain order, so it's not about the loops or about java vs groovy, is about the threads.

Answer (score 8):

A Java closure closes over the *immutable value* in `f` when created, while the Groovy closure closes over the *mutable variable* `f`.

So once the Groovy loop finishes, `f` contains `5` and threads that happen to run after that will print `5`.

**Java closures** can close over a variable reference that's final or “effectively final” meaning that it’s final in all but name. See [Java 8: Lambdas, Part 1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-lambdas-part1-2080972.html). That's what inner classes can do plus some useful convenience.

**Groovy closures** are very different objects, and they predate Java closures. See [Groovy Closures](http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html), where the example `{ ++item }` modifies a variable from the enclosing scope.

> Groovy defines closures as instances of the Closure class. It makes it very different from [lambda expressions in Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). Delegation is a key concept in Groovy closures which has no equivalent in lambdas. The ability to change the delegate or change the delegation strategy of closures make it possible to design beautiful domain specific languages (DSLs) in Groovy.

**Bottom line** Groovy aims to be the dynamic language with the best "impedance match" to Java, but now that Java has lambdas, the two languages continue to diverge. Caveat programmer.

Comment: since F is inside closure, we expect it to be final, isn't it?

Comment: Not in Groovy. Groovy closures are very different than (and predate) Java closures. I'll add more info to the answer above.

Comment: Java doesn't have closures! Lambda's are *not* closures. Groovy and JavaScript have closures. Java doesn't.

Comment: Why do you say that, @Andreas? Java, Groovy, and JavaScript each have different semantics, but they each have closures that close over things in the containing scope. In Java, they close over final values. In JavaScript, they close over references to mutable variables. In Groovy, they close over references to mutable variables and have delegates and other special features. In C++, you can specify which containing values and variables to close over.

Comment: @Jerry101 You will not find the word "closure" in the Java Language Specification. Java doesn't close over anything. It's compiler syntactic sugar for copying the value.

Comment: @Andreas You are right about JLS (ignoring occurrences of "transitive closure"). Why is that? Java's closures certainly fit the definition in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming). The article's "Differences in semantics" section specifically contrasts languages like ECMAScript which capture variables "by reference" vs. Java which captures variables "by value" and C++11 where `[&]` captures by reference while `[=]` captures by value.

Comment: ... and Haskell which binds to result values of future computations rather than values or variables.

Comment: A "closure" is "closed" to the environment, in contrast to a lambda in early versions of Lisp that was "open" to the environment, meaning it would look up bindings in the current call stack when run. In this case, an open lambda would look up `f`, and fail to find `f` since the lambda provides the thread's `run()` method, there's nothing further up the call stack.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an issue with the "Closure implementation" in Groovy.

It is with your misunderstanding of what a Closure is.

First of all, it is *not* the same as an anonymous method (class) or Lambda (Java 8+).
It *is* the same as a JavaScript closure.

A closure has full read/write access to local variables that are in scope, meaning variables defined in the enclosing method, but outside the closure. Those variables exist and can be updated by any code with access to them, and they continue to exist after the method defining them exits (returns).

You really should read much more about closures, either in Groovy or JavaScript documentation and examples. JavaScript is rife with use of closures, so you'll find lots of documentation on the subject.

Here's a short intro:

```
def a() {
    def myval = 0
    return { x -> myval += x } // <-- Returns a closure
}
def f = a()
print f(5)
print f(7)
```

This will print `5` and `12`, because the variable `myval` exists as long as the closure assigned to `f` stays alive.

Or here is the JavaScript version: https://jsfiddle.net/Lguk9qgw/

In contrast, Java cannot do that, because Java doesn't have closures, not even with the new Lambdas. Java's anonymous classes, and their Lambda equivalent, require all outside variables to be invariant, i.e. `final`, whether explicitly defined that way, or inferred by the compiler (new in Java 8).

This is because Java in reality *copies* the value, and requiring the value to be `final` ensures that you don't notice, unless you disassemble the generated bytecode.

To show this, these 5 Java examples all do the same thing, functionally, e.g. calling `test1().applyAsInt(5)` will return `12`:

```
// Using Lambda Expression
public static IntUnaryOperator test1() {
    final int f = 7;
    return x -> x + f;
}

// Using Lambda Block
public static IntUnaryOperator test2() {
    final int f = 7;
    return x -> { return x + f; };
}

// Using Anonymous Class
public static IntUnaryOperator test3() {
    final int f = 7;
    return new IntUnaryOperator() {
        @Override public int applyAsInt(int operand) { return operand + f; }
    };
}

// Using Local Class
public static IntUnaryOperator test4() {
    final int f = 7;
    class Test4 implements IntUnaryOperator {
        @Override public int applyAsInt(int operand) { return operand + f; }
    }
    return new Test4();
}

// Using Nested Class
private static final class Test5 implements IntUnaryOperator {
    private final int f;
    Test5(int f) { this.f = f; }
    @Override public int applyAsInt(int operand) { return operand + this.f; }
}
public static IntUnaryOperator test5() {
    final int f = 7;
    return new Test5(f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know the reason for loop specified in question, but followin code snippet works like a charm:

```
["one","two","three","four"].each { tid ->
    Thread.start {
        println "Thread $tid says Hello World!"
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because the `tid` in the `each` closure is a new instance of a variable every time.  In the `for` loop, the same variable `f` is reused

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of code decompilation:

```
CallSite[] arrayOfCallSite = $getCallSiteArray();
Object arr = ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createList(new Object[] { Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(2), Integer.valueOf(3), Integer.valueOf(4), Integer.valueOf(5) });
Reference f = new Reference(Integer.valueOf(0));
for (Iterator i = (Iterator)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(arrayOfCallSite[0].call(arr), Iterator.class); i.hasNext();) {
    ((Reference)f).set(Integer.valueOf(DefaultTypeTransformation.intUnbox(i.next())));
    arrayOfCallSite[1].call(Thread.class, new _main_closure1(Test.class, Test.class, f));
}
```

From this snippet is seen that every Thread gets the same instance of f

Comment: I believe each thread gets their own reference. The code that you provided creates iterator over the original array arr. And then iterates over it: 
(Reference)f).set(Integer.valueOf(DefaultTypeTransformation.intUnbox(i.next())));
    arrayOfCallSite[1].call(Thread.class, new _main_closure1(Test.class, Test.class, f));

Did I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the following line

```
for (int f in arr) {
```

to

```
arr.each { f->
```

you will get the result you get in java