# Grails 2.4 issue while iterating over list, set or map to create some threads

Tags: grails

Grails 2.4 is not able to iterate over list, set or map. while code is working fine in Java.

```
public void createData(){
    Set<String> entries = new HashSet<String>();
    entries.add("a");
    entries.add("b");
    entries.add("c");
    ThreadGroup tg = new ThreadGroup("Async Threads");

    for(final String entry : entries){
        new Thread(tg, "xyz"){
            public void run(){
                System.out.println(entry);
            }
        }.start();
    }    
}
```

Output in Grails 2.4 with Java 7

```
a
b
b
```

Output in Java 7

```
a
b
c
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Look that: [For loop works different in Groovy and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283443/for-loop-works-different-in-groovy-and-java?answertab=votes#tab-top)

And try to do like this:

```
    Set<String> entries = new HashSet<String>();
    entries.add('a');
    entries.add('b');
    entries.add('c');
    final ThreadGroup tg = new ThreadGroup('Async Threads');

    for (final String entry : entries) {
        new Thread(tg, entry) {
            void run() {
                println(name)
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

You will see groovy code working fine